# CRM 2011 Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception while creating new Acount

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Hi I am getting the following erro while creating new Account in CRM 2011. Any suggestions please.

Thanks

**Unhandled Exception:**

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Detail:
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">0</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2012-04-02T11:03:57.7288333Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>[AutoNumberGenerator: AutoNumberGenerator.AutoNumberGenerator] [9202e5b5-d848-e111-8920-0050569b0118: AutoNumberGenerator.AutoNumberGenerator: Create of account]    
</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<TraceText>[AutoNumberGenerator: AutoNumberGenerator.AutoNumberGenerator] [9202e5b5-d848-e111-8920-0050569b0118: AutoNumberGenerator.AutoNumberGenerator: Create of account]
```

The line above says that there is a plug-in called **AutoNumberGenerator**.
And the exception being thrown is thrown from this plug-in.

Comment: thanks @Anwar, I am looking into it. Its not just that plugin. Its something to to with the else as well. Because the same plugin in working properly on other machines. May be its not registered properly.

Comment: Check if that plug-in requires any configuration entities within the CRM system, and if so check if those records are there. Some autonumber plug-ins may use this for storing a counter or referencing a particular schema for the autonumber generation (prefix/suffix format for example).